# Android Studio Gradle build runs forever

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, gradlew, ubuntu-16.04

I just installed `Ubuntu 16.04` and Android Studio on my notebook. When trying to build a project, the gradle build doesn't finish (it ran for more than an hour). The one and only line in the EventLog is:

```
"Executing tasks: [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies]".
```

I installed the 32-bit version of linux. Also `zlib1g` appears to be installed, which i found out is a common reason for this problem. I also tickled the "Work Offline" option in the Gradle settings.

Any ideas on that issue?

Thx for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself a while ago. So just in case someone has the same problem:

Android stopped supporting 32-bit OSes from buildToolsVersion 24. So, if you have the same problem and you're using buildTools 24 or higher, just set them to 23 in your build.gradle file, sync, and you should be ok.